# What are "use-cases" in the Clean Architecture?

Tags: javascript, node.js, clean-architecture

I am trying to implement the Clean Architecture structure in an app that I am developing and I am having a hard time figuring out exactly what is what.

For example, if I am right, the entities of my appliaction are `Employee`, `Department`, `EmployeeSkill` the entities also include all of the "validation" logic, to ensure that these entities are valid.

And the use-cases are the various actions that I can do with these entities?

For example, use-cases about the `Employee`:

```
add-employee.js
remove-employee-by-id.js
update-employee-department.js
update-employee-phone-number.js
...and-more-employee-updates.js
```

Are these all actually use-cases?

Now the `add` and `remove` i dont think have much to discuss about, but what about the updates? Should they be `granulated` like this?

Also with such architecture, doesnt that mean that, I if I want to update both the employees department and phone number at the same time, I will have to make two separate calls to the database, for something that can be done with one, because the database adapter is being injected into the use case, and every use case starts with "finding" the entity in the database?

Answer (score 1):

Defer thinking about the entities for now. Often, you get stuck trying to abstract the code after your mental model of the world and that is not as helpful as we are lead to believe.

Instead, couple code that change together for one reason into use-cases. A good start can be one for each crud operation in the GUI. what will be  by a new method, or new parameter, or new class etc is not part of the CA pattern, that is part of the normal tradeoffs you face when you write code.

I can't see any entities from your example. In my code base ContactCard (I work on an yellow pages in 2021 kind of app) and UserContext (security) are the only entities, these two things are used all over the place.

Other things are just data holders and not really an entity. I have many duplicates of the data holders so that things that are not coupled, stay uncoupled.

Your repository should probably implement the bridge pattern. That means that the business logic defines a bridge, that some repository implements. The use-case is not aware of database tables, so it does not have any granular requirements (think if it as ordering food at mcdonalds, it won't say from the grill I want xxx, and from the fryer I want yyy).

The use case is very demanding in the bridge definition. So much, that many repositories end up having api layers that import and manage the implementation of the bridge, and then they adapters to the internal logic.

This is the difference between api layers in business apps and most B2C apis. An enterprise API for an use case, is the just what the use-case needed.

If you have already constrained yourself by a made up model of the world, and decided to split repos in that, instead of splitting them per use-case, then  you end up with poor alignment. Having the same sql query, or parts of it, in more than one repository is not an issue. Over time, the queries look different a lot of the time even if they start out very similar.

I would call your example use-case for UpdatePhoneNumberEverywhere. And then the UpdatePhoneNumberEverywhereRepository implementation, can do what the heck it wants to, that is a detail. The use case does not care.

Another one I might do is UpdatePhoneNumber and the use-case accepts a strategy. Strategy.CASCADE or Strategy.Leaf etc.

In terms of your table design, even though it's a detail, Contacts probably deserves to be broken out.

Every use-case does not start with finding something from the database. Commands and queries are passed in or w/e you call it, and the use-case does something useful.

The most practical way to write a use-case, is to just implement exactly what you need for the business requirement, write all the tests against the public api in the use-case. Just pass in data as a start, a dictionary is often fine.

Entities are often found later when you cannot stand to have so many versions of something, you just need that something to be stable and the same all over, and your end users expects as much too. Then, just refactor.